# Tracking java exceptions by hooking into the JVM

Tags: java

Yourkit's got a pretty neat feature that will basically track any exceptions being thrown in the JVM. I was wondering how they did that.  Specifically, I'd like the ability check a log file and see how many and what exceptions are being thrown.  Obviously logging seems like it can play a part here, but I'm really looking for a solution that doesn't require any work by developers.

Is there a way to hook into the JVM via jmx or by using a custom javaagent?

Thanks!

Comment: Java's JDI debug facilities provide a lot of capabilities.

Comment: In particular, [com.sun.jdi.event.ExceptionEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/event/ExceptionEvent.html).

Comment: Interesting. I haven't looked at JDI before.  Hopefully today I can carve out some time today and get something put together.